# Arquitetura projeto ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, arquitetura-de-software

Qual seria a melhor forma de armazenar arquivos de usuário de acordo com os requisitos abaixo:

- O usuário pode enviar um ou diversos arquivos de uma vez;
- Os tipo de arquivos aceitos por toda aplicação são: mp3, jpg, png, xls, doc, ppt e pdf;
- A arquitetura é toda baseada em serviços WCF onde existem 2 projetos. O projeto de UI que é feito em ASP NET MVC 4 com a versão do framework 4.5 e o projeto de WCF também em .NET 4.5 . O banco de dados é o Sql Server 2012;

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:
Tendo este cenário qual seria a melhor forma de armazenar estes arquivos? Serializando os arquivos e armazenando no banco, salvar o arquivo direto no hd do servidor (upload comum) e armazenar as informações básicas do arquivo para relacionar a um usuário ou trabalhar com FileTables do Sql Server 2012?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trabalho com esse tipo de informação diariamente e posso afirmar que o ideal é ter os arquivos salvos em um servidor de arquivos, salvando-os em uma estrutura de pastas que facilite a busca deles, e no banco de dados apontar para esse diretório. Também vale a pena rever a estrutura do servidor de arquivos, de preferência trabalhe com no mínimo dois HD's em RAID ou mantenha um outro servidor sincronizado para realizar a redundância e oferecer um serviço de primeira.

Caso escolha a outra opção em breve preencherá o limite de dados estabelecido pela versão Express e terá que comprar uma outra versão.

Comment: Felipe,
Eu estou pensando em optar por salvar os arquivos em disco mesmo, porém, outras pessoas na equipe preferem salvar em banco por dois motivos. Migração de servidor e backup do sistema que seria mais fácil.
Mas acredito que o melhor caminho será arquivos em disco mesmo (apesar da infra não ser nossa).

Comment: Perfeito, show de bola! No caso da minha equipe também não trabalhamos com infra própria, mas solicitamos espelhamento do disco e se um cair o outro servidor que tem o HD espelhado assume.

Comment: Porquê você achar que migração e backup seriam mais fáceis persistindo os arquivos em banco? Dependendo do sistema os arquivos vão superar em muito o tamanho do banco deixando-o mais lento inclusive para operações de backup

Comment: A minha opinião e a do Thiago não é essa, dissemos acima que preferimos salvar em um diretório o arquivo e salvar o caminho dele no banco.

Comment: Estou estudando uma outra forma na qual o SQL Server 2012 faz o gerenciamento dos arquivos. Os arquivos são salvos no disco, porém, o gerenciamento dos mesmos é feito pelo SQL Server 2012. Isso é feito através do FileTables. Pode ser uma boa opção também. Alguém já trabalhou dessa forma?

Comment: Muito interessante, inclusive para quem está enfrentando problemas com servidor de arquivos, pois ele simula o servidor de arquivos, faz parecer que está em um servidor de arquivos por ser filestream, é uma excelente opção para quem quiser trocar o velho servidor de arquivos por uma licença do SQLServer, pois atingirá facilmente os limites da versão express.